# How to set column type to integer with the data containing $ symbol in datatables

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have a users grid, where one column contains total due. I am appending '$' symbol to each due value in the rows. Now the data table considering this column as string and sorting it as string. How can I convert the string type to integer type.

Values are like Below:

```
Due
---
$88.00
$0.00
$0.00
$942.99
$0.00
$230.00
$0.00
$84.60
```

when I click sort button, it is sorting like

```
Due
---
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00
$230.00
$84.60
$88.00
$942.99
```

I want the result like below

```
Due
---
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00    
$84.60
$88.00
$230.00
$942.99
```

This is happening because of the '$' symbol. But I need that symbol to be there. I have seen some documentation here https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type , but that is not helpful for me.

Comment: 2 options: use [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to concatenate the symbol and value, I'm fairly sure the column will still sort on the underlying column data. Second option is to have a hidden column containing the value, and use [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) to sort on it instead of the displayed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you are using the [currency sorting plugin](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency), a very small add-on :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "currency-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
    },
    "currency-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },
    "currency-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
});
```

Include that code, or refer to it through the CDN, and specify your columnn as type currency in columnDefs :

```js
columnDefs: [
   { type: 'currency', targets: 0 }
]
```

where `targets` is the column index; `targets` can also be an array of column indexes, like `[3, 8, 12]`.

demo with your values above (using the currency plugin through CDN) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3tdcje7y/**

Comment: Thanks davidkonrad for the answer and fiddle. I am using the dataTables version 1.9.2. The currency plugin didn't worked with the 1.9.2 version. Like you(in Fiddle, you have used 1.10), I have changed the version from 1.9.2 to  1.10. After that it worked like a charm, even without the currency plugin.